# Only pdo_sqlsrv is loaded in php info

Tags: php, sql-server, pdo, sqlsrv

[image]

I am trying mssql first time, however after googling i could only load pdo_sqlsrv. Is that ok? Is there any way to load sqlsrv without pdo ?

(Using XAMPP 3.2.2, PHP V 5.5.38)

Comment: Consider to update your php 5.5 - it's not supported anymore and it does not get any security updates - EOL! see here: http://php.net/supported-versions.php

Comment: @BerndOtt, just now i have updated to PHP 7.1 and now both sqlsrv and pdo_sqlsrv is active. Thanks anyway :)

Answer (score 0):

Check for startup errors (need to be enabled in php config).

I guess a vc runtime or the sql native client is missing.

Comment: Thanks for comment however i have updated PHP to 7.1 and now both sqlsrv and pdo_sqlsrv is active. :)